# Group by and show all rows

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table called payment. Which has `payid`, `date`, `productid`, `customerid`, `Name`, `type`, `colour`, `quantity`, `total`.

Multiple items can be entered into the table with the same timestamp.

I am trying to group the data by date. I have got the date to display only once using count but it will only display the first item with the time stamp.

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");

//echo "1"; 
$get_orders_date = mysql_query("SELECT date, name, COUNT( DISTINCT date) FROM payment GROUP BY date");

//echo "2"; 

while($get_date = mysql_fetch_array($get_orders_date)) 
{   
    //echo "3"; 

    $date = $get_date['date'];  
    echo "" .$date. "<br/><br/>";
    $name = $get_date['name'];  
    echo "" .$name. "<br/><br/>";
}

?>
```

This will display the date and time the item was paid for but only one of the items.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you post some sample data from the table and the desired result?

Comment: Got it sort, figured it out myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by both name and date.

Also keep in mind that MySQL violates standards by executing this query. If using grouping, all nongrouped columns should have an aggregate function applied to them.

Comment: have added the group by name. It is given me date item, date item, date item...... I am trying to get date item item... date item ite...

Comment: I try to use min(name) instead of using GROUP BY name